# Will @Extra automatically restore data when app process was killed?

Tags: android-annotations

For example,app was not visible in the background,system need memory for other app and kill the app process,then user restart the app.Will the @Extra annotation restore the data automatically？

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Comment: Sorry,i don't know why i can't simulate the low memory state in my phone...When i can perform the state i'll post the answer.

Comment: You can simulate this easily. Turn on "Do not keep Activities" in the developer options. Then open your app, send it back then make it foreground again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Extra is for extracting the extras from the Intents coming to your Activity. To save and restore fields you should use @InstanceState. You can annotate the same field which you already has @Extra.

BTW AndroidAnnotations is just a wrapper, so these concepts are coming from core Android.